# Multi threaded download for java

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications, server, download

Am trying to give a portal for download using Java - Spring where the file may be about 1 GB and the application will be hosted in a Server and can be accessed throughout the world.

Can I make that download to be multithreaded or make it much faster?

Comment: Multithreading lets you parallelize your processing. For a file download, that's most likely not where your bottleneck is; it's more likely to be network communication or disk IO.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen  do u have any smaple code for that in java or procedure to achieve that ?

Comment: Achieve what? Multithreading a file download? I don't think there's a point: speed of sending bytes over network < speed of reading bytes from disk < speed of processing bytes. You're trying to optimize what's already the fastest link in the chain.

Comment: Having another doubt where the client uploads a File of 1 GB and whether the upload can be made multithreaded and can we make it fast?